# javascript gotcha: empty list to boolean conversion

Tags: javascript

Why both

```
 [] == false
```

and

```
![] == false
```

are true?

Answer (score 15):

The === operator is your friend. Never use the == operator; it will bite you, as you can see.

Comment: Although your answer is helpful it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: True. The values that are "false" are: undefined, null, false, 0, and "". As mikesamuel says, [] coerces to "". So much for the first one. And a non-null object reference is true, which answers the second one.

Answer (score 11):

An empty list, `[]` must be considered a "falsey", however in `![]` the ! is then converting the operation to check for an *object reference*, where a non-null is not considered a "falsey".

Comment: [] is not falsey.  It's a side effect of string coercion.
The array [''] is also == false, but is not falsey.

Answer (score 5):

Before [] is compared to false, it is coerced to a string which is coerced to a number, the empty string in the case of the empty array.  The empty string coerces to 0 which is the same value that false coerces to numerically.

Use === instead of == to avoid this problem

These other arrays are also falsey:

```
  ['']
  [[[]]]
  (function () { var arr = []; arr[0] = arr; })()
  [0]
  ['-0.0']
```

Comment: why would a list be coerced to string when compared with a boolean value? Any sources?

Comment: From section 11.9.3 of EcmaScript 262:
    18. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y. 
    19. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

Then coercing an Array to a number consists of first coercing it to a string and then coercing that string to a number.  For most arrays, that will yield the non-comparable value NaN, but for some arrays, [], [0], [[0]], ['0.0'], etc. they will compare truthfully with false.

You can experimient with the coercion behavior by evaluating (+[0]) etc.